# How to handle multiple client with SOAP?

Tags: php, c++, soap

I'm having two clients from PHP calling a c/c++ function getNumber(); repeatly, and from c server it generate a number one at a time. now what it does is each generated number can be recieved from on client only and the rest will recieve the next generated number. for example

client A and B.

generated number: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

client A will finally recieved 1,3,5,7,9
and B will recieved 2,4,6,8

How can I create a function that A and B can recieved all generated number?

What if there are ten or thousand clients?

Thanks

Comment: where is the problem in your PHP code ?

Comment: Are you trying to setup a function that increments and stores a number? Your question confuses me... why would A/B receive ALL generated numbers? Are you trying to give a incremented number upon each request?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways that I can think of that you can approach this.

First of you can structure your server so that it remembers some state information about each client, given that your using SOAP you'll probably have to add some kind of unique id token to the message, possibly genenerated by the server on the first call from the client (or a call with no such id token).  and then maintain a state database in the server that allows you to process each call.

Second way may not be appropriate but if the next value in your sequence can be determined from the previous value then make each client provide the previous value as part of the next call.  You'd need to define some special starting value that indicates that this is a new client.

Method 1 has the advanatge of working with any type of data but at the cost of needing a database of state information to be held at the server, and if you need the server to be restartable the data would have to be persisted.

Method 2 puts less demands on the server but won't work for all data sequences.